# Canvas mouse event and focus

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, mouseevent

I have 2 circles and one line. The circles have a move option (u can press them and move). Mousemove event have a variable `distance` to calculate the distance between mouse and the circle.

The problem is, that when you move one circle to another close enough, they will join. How to avoid that? Is there an option to make some focus or something like that? Any ideas how to fix that (is it possible?)

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/cs5Sg/7/):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    radius = 12,
    p = null,
    start = false;

    point = {
        p1: { x:100, y:250 },
        p2: { x:400, y:100 }
    }

function init() {
        return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    start = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    start = false;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

    for (p in point) {
        if(start) {
            var 
                mouseX = e.clientX -10,
                mouseY = e.clientY -10,
                distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - point[p].x, 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - point[p].y, 2));

            if (distance -10<= radius) {
                point[p].x = e.clientX -10 ;
                point[p].y = e.clientY -10 ;
            } 

        }
    }
});


function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(point.p1.x,point.p1.y);
    context.lineTo(point.p2.x,point.p2.y);

    context.closePath();

    context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();

    for (p in point) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(point[p].x,point[p].y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
    }
    context.closePath();
}

init();
```

​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save which point was pressed in your `mousedown` event.

Like that: http://jsfiddle.net/cs5Sg/9/

In addition, it will not calculate the distance to each point every time the mouse moves so it will be faster.

Comment: I have one question - why moving is false? Why not null for example? Is there any difference?

Comment: It's an habit, but null would work, true. I think false is a bit more explicit, but it's only my opinion.